# How do I resize and svg logo in react gatsby?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, gatsby

[image]

I have been trying to resize this logo without making the container itself larger. I'm completely stuck and dont know what to do. Modifying the logo svg file with inline styling
 `<svg viewBox="0 0 493.19 493.19" width='400'height='400'>` produces the above result. I just want to make the logo bigger without pushing down all the components under it. I will post the layout code itself, if that will make things easier to help me out. Thank you!

````
  const data: QueryResult = useStaticQuery(query)

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <>
        <GlobalStyles />
        <Wrapper>
          <SideBarInner bg={color} as="aside" p={[6, 6, 8]}>
            <Flex
              flexWrap="nowrap"
              flexDirection={['row', 'row', 'row', 'column']}
              alignItems={['center', 'center', 'center', 'flex-start']}
              justifyContent="space-between"
            >
              <Box width={['3rem', '4rem', '5rem', '8rem']}>
                <Link to="/" aria-label="LekoArts, Back to Home">
                  <Logo />
                </Link>
              </Box>
              <Nav
                color={color}
                mt={[0, 0, 0, 10]}
                as="nav"
                flexWrap="nowrap"
                flexDirection={['row', 'row', 'row', 'column']}
                alignItems="flex-start"
              >
                {data.navigation.nodes.map((item) => (
                  <PartialNavLink to={item.link} key={item.name}>
                    {item.name}
                  </PartialNavLink>
                ))}
              </Nav>
            </Flex>
          </SideBarInner>
          <Main>{children}</Main>
          <Footer color={color}>
            <Box p={[6, 6, 8]} fontSize={0}>
              little things with love <a href="https://www.lekoarts.de/en">LekoArts</a>.<br />
              <a href="https://github.com/LekoArts/gatsby-starter-portfolio-jodie">Source</a>.
            </Box>
          </Footer>
        </Wrapper>
      </>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default Layout```
````

Answer (score 1):

The SVG viewBox dimensions don't change the size of the paths in the SVG, they change the size of the SVG object that contains the paths which results with that extra white-space.

I would undo the changes you made to the viewBox and remove the width and height inline styles. Then, the SVG should resize automatically to fit the container that it is in.

Comment: That was its default state, the svg was small and in the corner of the container..

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `width` to `100%` in the `svg` code and then control the size of `svg` with CSS (however you are implmenting css) by adjusting the `width` of the container that holds the `svg`.

Something like:

```css
.sl-container {
    width: 4rem;
}
```

EDIT:
If you need help implementing the css you can find a good explanation of numerous implmentations [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/style-react-components-styled-components/). Inline styling is probably the simplest way to do it.

```html
<Logo style="width: 4rem;" />
```

Comment: what does .sl-container point to? this is all done in react, there isn't a seperate css file. There is only a layout.tsx file. I don't know how I can just assign a class to the svg and change width like it's traditionally done.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide some additional reference for implementing css in react.

Comment: that did nothing assuming I put it in the right place 
`const Logo = () => (
  <svg viewBox="0 0 493.19 493.19" style="width: 4rem;">

    <title>callmeJ</title>
    <path  d="M183.21,42.4c0-5.42-2/> </svg>`

Comment: wrap the svg in a div tag and put the inline style in the div